# How to access same variable name inside function in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to access same variable name inside function in javascript

```
var xyz = "Hello";
console.log("outside function: " + xyz)
function abc() {
    var xyz = "World!";
    console.log("inside function: " + xyz) // output should be "Hello world!"
} abc();
```

Comment: How about only using `console.log("inside function: " + xyz + " World!")` inside the function without assigning any value to `xyz`.

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
var xyz = "Hello";
console.log("outside function: " + xyz)
function abc() {
    var xyz = (window.xyz || "") +" " + "World!";
    console.log("inside function: " + xyz) // output should be "Hello world!"
} abc();
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) Anupam, such a quick reply. Got it

Answer (score 2):

if you do not want to edit the value of xyz:

```
var xyz = "Hello";
console.log("outside function: " + xyz)
function abc() {
    var abc = " World!";
    console.log("inside function: " + xyz + abc) // output should be "Hello world!"
} abc();
```

if you want to edit the value of xyz:

```
var xyz = "Hello";
console.log("outside function: " + xyz)
function abc() {
    xyz += " World!";
    console.log("inside function: " + xyz) // output should be "Hello world!"
} abc();
```

Comment: Thank You!! Christopher. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try with window. This will allow you to access globally declared variable.

`var xyz = window.xyz` ..

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass it as a parameter?
There is absolutely no need to use a [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_variable) variable.

```
var xyz = "Hello";
console.log("outside function: " + xyz)
function abc(xyz) {
    var xyzUpdated = xyz + "World!";
    console.log("inside function: " + xyzUpdated) // output should be "Hello world!"
} abc(xyz);
```